# How to use Xcode8 and Github for project collaboration between three developers?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

I would like to use Github to collaborate on an iOS application for a university project. Myself and two other students are developing this application and will each be creating different modules within the application. I know how to use Github for personal Xcode projects but can't quite understand how to do this for multi-developer projects. If I create a repo on Github and push an Xcode project to it, what is the best way for the others to add to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do the same as you; they just add/commit/push their changes.

The difference is you occasionally need to do a pull or fetch/rebase to get the changes others have pushed into your local repo.

Lots of online help for this, but the short answer is still the same.

Comment: Would they just fork the repo to their Github account first and then clone the forked repo locally?

Comment: No need to fork.  Just clone the repo locally.  If you do 'git clone' it will set up the github repo as the "remote" which is where everyone' updates go when they "push".

git is not really trivial, though, and you can get yourself in a mess if you aren't careful.  I recommend going through some online tutorials and maybe reading some books before you get too far down the road.

Comment: This book from the Git website might be helpful, particularly sections 6.2 and 6.3: [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)